# unable to set the shortcut for "Switch applications"

Tags: 13.04, shortcut-keys

I tried to change the shortcut for "Switch applications" in `Settings`->`Keyboard`->`Shortcuts`, but it does not work. The UI simply lies.

Comment: Have you installed somehow CompizConfig Settings Manager?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu No, I haven't tried that. I used Ubuntu's `Settings` app.

Comment: What shortcut do you want to add?